# TabLayout only change color text when do scroll, not when click

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tabLayout with a small problem. The tab change the icon and the text color when I do scroll in the differents tabs. That's work fine.

The problem is when I try to do a click in the tab (not scrolling). When I do this, I always have two tabs with the same color text. I only want to have the select tab with the correct color text. The icon is change correctly.

Tab xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorSecundary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabText"
        />

<style name="CustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

The code:

```
 private void initTabs(){
        pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_view_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ProfileFragment.ProfilePageAdapter(getFragmentManager()));


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_activity_fill));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_favourites_fill));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_reputation));

    setTypeFace();

}

private void setTypeFace(){
    Typeface tfGothamRoundedMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(ApplicationConfig.getAppContext().getAssets(), Comunes.TypeGothamRoundedMedium);

    ViewGroup tablayoutView = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);

    for(int x = 0;x<3;x++) {
        ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) tablayoutView.getChildAt(x);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = tabView.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) child).setTypeface(tfGothamRoundedMedium);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_activity_fill));

    } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_favourites));

    } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_reputation_fill));

    }
    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), Boolean.TRUE);
    setTypeFace();
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_activity));
    } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_favourites_fill));
    } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
        tab.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ico_reputation));
    }
    setTypeFace();
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a issue of android, they say is closed, but still happening to me.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178650

The solution i found, is set the 'selected' property of the text view to false. Here a example, where i get every tab and if the position (x) is different to my selected tab, i set the selected property to false.

```
for(int x = 0;x<3;x++) {
            ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) tablayoutView.getChildAt(x);

            for (int i = 0; i < tabView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = tabView.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) child).setTypeface(tfGothamRoundedMedium, Typeface.NORMAL);
                    if ( x != position  ) {
                        child.setSelected(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, it is working properly, this does not look like a proper way to change the icons of the tabs. Instead of overriding **onTabSelected()** and **onTabUnselected()** methods, just create selectors for your icons in the drawable folder. Like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_white" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_light_grey"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Then set that in this ways:
`tabLayout.getTabAt(X).setIcon(R.drawable.your_tab_selector)`

I believe the reason you get the same text color when you click on a tab is that you change the type face of your tabs, thus the colors set in the XML for your TabView are overridden.

Comment: Hi, I've removed the setType and is not working. Thanks for the recomendation to change the icons!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the effect by using addOnPageChangeListener on view pager and on each position set the tabLayout and status bar color too for >21

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    try {
                        type = position;
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
                                        mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
                                        mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                    Window window = getWindow();
                                    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                                    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
                                            mContext.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                -----
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                -----
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                -----
                                break;
                            default:
                                -----
                                break;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
                            if (i == position) {
                                tab.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
                            } else {
                                tab.getIcon().setAlpha(125);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```